# Jut get as result: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Can someone help me out?
I just get as result tb_localidade: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

Why? Here is the code:

```
private void btn_normalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //connection string - one or other doenst work
    //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("DataSource=FRANCISCO_GP;Initial Catalog=Normalizacao;Integrated Security=True;");

   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connString);

   string sql = "SELECT ART_DESIG from Arterias where ART_COD = '10110'";

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

   conn.Open();

   SqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   tb_localidade.Text = leitor.ToString();

   conn.Close();
```

}

Comment: Did you search for any example on how to use a DataReader? There are a lot around and none uses ToString to retrieve the content of a record

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your title and body

Comment: What you really want is ExecuteScalar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling `Read()` on your data reader and assigning the results:

```
private void btn_normalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT ART_DESIG from Arterias where ART_COD = '10110'";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            SqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (leitor.Read())
            {
                tb_localidade.Text = leitor["ART_DESIG"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another note is that using a `using` block for your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects is a good habit to get into.

*Note:  this is assigning the result to the `tb_localidade.Text` for **every row** in the resultset.  If you are only intending for this to be one record, you might want to look into `.ExecuteScalar()` instead (see below).*

```
private void btn_normalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT ART_DESIG from Arterias where ART_COD = '10110'";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            tb_localidade.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before execute "executeReader()" then you must read to get results.

Answer (score 0):

Improvement on Siyual's response.  You're only looking for a single result, and this explicitly disposes both the connection and the datareader.

```
private void btn_normalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT ART_DESIG from Arterias where ART_COD = '10110'";

        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {

            using(SqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
                if (leitor.Read())
                {
                    tb_localidade.Text = leitor["ART_DESIG"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should just this

```
SqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string res="";
while(leitor.Read())
{
    res=leitor.GetValue(0).ToString()///////if in sql it is varchar or nvarshar
}

tb_localidade.Text = res;
```

actully datareader is a 1d table and we can access to this with GetValue or GetInt32 or ...